# Specified cast is not valid(C#,SQL)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime

I am trying to read the Date and Amount_Fuel from SQL to plot a bar graph of fuel consumption at weekly interval.The graph is supposed to plot Amount_Fuel against week(s).However,I am getting the 'Specified cast is not valid' error when reading Date with date_time/date data type and Amount_Fuel with int data type from a Fuel_Attended table in the SQL SERVER 2012. Here is the current code giving the highlighted error`

```
private void Load_BTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    try
    {      
        string selectQuery = "Select sum(Fuel_Amount), DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, '1950-01-01', Date), '1950-01-01') AS WeekNumber from Fuel_Attendend group by DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, '1950-01-01', Date), '1950-01-01')";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, connection);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                this.chart1.Series["Date"].Points.AddXY(dr.GetDateTime(0), dr.GetInt32(1));     
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Here is the table.[image: SQL TABLE]. 
Here is the error.[image: Error].Please help.

Comment: `Select sum(Fuel_Amount)` returns an `int` but `dr.GetDateTime(0)` is looking a `DateTime` from column 0.  Basically I think you have your columns mixed up.

Comment: Is it me, or it's should be `AddXY(dr.GetInt32(0),dr.GetDateTime(1));`?

Comment: @SeM I am still getting the same error if i do that.

Comment: @StephenWilson Do you suggest that I should first start with the Fuel_Amount column in the table?

Comment: Try to debug your code, separate your `dr.GetDateTime(0)` and `dr.GetInt32(1)` to variables, and see if you are getting your correct values. The if it is correct, then problem is not in reading data.

Answer (score 0):

```
 connection.Open();
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        this.chart1.Series["Date"].Points.AddXY(dr.GetInt32(1), dr.GetDateTime(0));

   }
```